# Vertical navigation bar does not fill 100% height of the screen when zoomed in

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a dashboard menu where I am using a vertical navigation bar for navigation. The navigation bar fills 100% height when there is no content in the right side of the pane.

It works perfectly when I zoom-in or zoom-out but when there are contents on the right side of the page the navigation bar doesn't fill the 100% of the page when I zoom-in.

The code styling for the navigation bar is given here:

```
.sidebar{

   position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:  #535392;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

The styling for the contents on the right side of the page is given here:

```
.PageContainer{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 70px;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the parent element properties

This is an easy fix , but the way of implementation of sidebar is not good enough i felt

Anyways , this is the issue :

In your code , Parent element height is not explicitly defined.That means , its height is depend on its children height (the height of the largest child will be taken)

Your sidebar height is in percentage(%) . Which depends on the other elements height

when you don't have other elements , it just takes your body's height.

But when you add some elements , then the hieght of your sidebar depends on those elements (in your case , pagecontainer)

**Quick - FIX**

```
.sidebar{bottom:0}
```

```css
.sidebar{

   position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:  #535392;
    display: table-cell;
    bottom:0;
}
.PageContainer{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 70px;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;

}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="sidebar">a</div>
<div class="PageContainer">dnfnsdf<div>
<div>
```

Comment: Incase , if your sidebar  size increases a lot when expanding the submenus then you should add scroll into the css  , and just decorate the css scroll 

Comment: The problem still exists. Please help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: @AbilashJayanandan can you provide the code with snippet . then only we can experiement and understand the real issue